# Changing current working directory to the directory from where script is running (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, directory

I have a python script located in `D:\Projects\`. It has a code that downloads files from web. By default files are getting downloaded in the default current working directory and not in the directory from where the script is running i.e. `D:\Projects\`

```
import os
os.getcwd()

O/P: 'C:\\Users\\<user_name>'
```

Do I have to manually change the current directory to the directory from where the script using `os.chdir(<path>)` command. Is there any other alternative.

Comment: Err, the current directory _is_ where the script is running. Unless you're running it from a different path.

Comment: In your case, the alternative would be to `chdir` into `D:\\Projects` and _then_ run your script.