# How to set the directory where the script is in in to working directory?

Tags: python

I want to import multiple files which will always be in the same directory as the script itself. But the script might be copied and pasted to somewhere else. I know how to set and change the working directory but I don't know how to set the working directory dynamically/automatically to where the `.py` file is located and run from.
The path must not be hard-coded.

I've seen [Changing current working directory to the directory from where script is running (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45861083/changing-current-working-directory-to-the-directory-from-where-script-is-running) but there is not really an answer.

Comment: heard about `os.path.dirname(__file__)` ?

Comment: No, how do I use it? I believe ___file___ is hard-coded?! The line returns "name '__file__' is not defined"?

Comment: it doesn't work from the interpreter. But from an existing file (save file first) it exists. Unless you're using python 2.5 where it's `sys.modules.__file__`